# Connecting SharePoint Online using Graph Service Client (Azure Functions, Asp.net core)

Tags: asp.net-core, upload, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, graphserviceclient

I am trying to upload pdf files of size 20 MB,30 MB etc. For this I am creating the upload session, creating a callback that is invoked after each slice is uploaded and then finally uploading the file.

First I read the bytes in memory stream and then
Taking slice size as 320*1024
and then do uploading.

But my file is uploading with no content. The reason is all bytes are  not uploading.
if my file size is 35303569bytes, only 35061760 bytes are uploaded.
No error is coming. When I check the file I could see the file in SharePoint site and when I open it there is no content.

Could anyone suggest me where I am going wrong or missing in the code.

Below is the code:

```
using (ms=new MemoryStream()) 
{ 
    byte[] bytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(data); 
    ms.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length); 
    ms.Seek(0,SeekOrigin.Begin); 
    var uploadSession =await graphclient.Sites[SiteId].Drive.Root.ItemWithPath(docfilename).CreateUploadSession().Request().PostAsync();

    var maxschinksize=320*1024;
    var largeuploadtask=new LargeUploadTask<DriveItem>(uploadsession,ms,maxchunksize)//ms is the memory stream in which I am reading the bytes.

    IProgress<long> uploadProgress=new Progress<long>(uploadbytes=>
    {

    }
    uploadResult=await largeuploadtask.UploadAsync(uploadprogress);
}
```

Comment: Looks like the remaining bytes 35303569-35061760=241809 bytes for the last slice are not send. Maybe bug in SDK and LargeUploadTask. What is the uploadResult returned by await largeuploadtask.UploadAsync(uploadprogress);?

Comment: @user2250152 Getting uploadResult. Itemresponse.AdditionalData, in this values are present in fields "odata.context"," Content.downloadUrl ".  Many other fields are also there.

Comment: What's the value of UploadSucceeded property in uploadResult?

Comment: @user2250152: UploadSucceeded property value is true.

Comment: do we need to provide mime type as well while uploading the file

Comment: Could you share more code? How do you read the file and stream?

Comment: @user2250152 using (ms=new MemoryStream())
            {             
                byte[] bytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(data);
                ms.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);                 
                ms.Seek(0,SeekOrigin.Begin);
                var uploadSession =await  graphclient.Sites[SiteId].Drive.Root
                                      .ItemWithPath(docfilename)
                                      .CreateUploadSession()
                                      .Request()
                                     .PostAsync();     Code after this is in ques.

Comment: Getting the input data in base64string format and then reading the data in memory stream.

Comment: @user2250152 do you any other detail to deep dive into it

Comment: string file = @"C:\Users\path\filename.pdf";
             string str = File.ReadAllText(file);
            byte[] bytes1 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);
             var size = str.Length;
             string stringbase64 = System.Convert.ToBase64String(bytes1); @user2250152 This is the way I am reading file. Converting to base64string because I need this at the time of hitting the API from postman

Answer (score 0):

There was some issue within my code only.
I was reading the content of file and it's encoding was also changing.
That means content that I was converting into base64string is not the original content.
All bytes were uploading, problem was with content.
Now, I used online converter to convert file to  base64 string and it worked.